# Prevent subcontainer objects in PrincipalSearcher Query C#

Tags: c#, directoryservices, userprincipal

How can I prevent subcontainer objects in queries to a specific OU with subcontainers (child OU)?

To clarify, I don't want to include user objects in children OUs (subcontainers) in the result set.

Given something like the code on [another stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627428/how-can-%20i-overcome-late-binding-in-active-directory-search/627931#627931) for example:

```
// create a principal object representation to describe
// what will be searched 
UserPrincipal user = new UserPrincipal(adPrincipalContext);

// define the properties of the search (this can use wildcards)
user.Enabled = false;
user.Name = "user*";

// create a principal searcher for running a search operation
PrincipalSearcher pS = new PrincipalSearcher();

// assign the query filter property for the principal object 
// you created
// you can also pass the user principal in the 
// PrincipalSearcher constructor
pS.QueryFilter = user;

// run the query
PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = pS.FindAll();

Console.WriteLine("Disabled accounts starting with a name of 'user':");
foreach (Principal result in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine("name: {0}", result.Name);
}
```

Thanks,

Victor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this (and a few other) features aren't visible directly on the `PrincipalSearcher` class.

You need to "reach down" to the underlying `DirectorySearcher` to set options like this (and e.g. the page size):

```
DirectorySearcher ds = pS.GetUnderlyingSearcher() as DirectorySearcher;

if(ds != null)
{
   ds.SearchScope = SearchScope.Base;  // or SearchScope.OneLevel - your pick
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marc!!! That's exactly what I was looking for! I had a really tough time finding the information for the search scope. After you specified it I found the corresponding MSDN information right away -- just had to know where to look I guess :)